# Is a gif or a moving image better for permormance?

Tags: html, css, image, gif

I'm making a button on the background with a .webp image moving back and forth using CSS keyframes.

Would putting a gif in there be more effective performance-wise?

Here's a video for visibility:
https://imgur.com/a/AFlJdat

Comment: Any answer to this should start”it all depends”. There’s not only the initial load to consider but what the animation is, eg whether a GPU would help, what quality is required, what browsers have to supported…. Why not try different methods on various systems and see if there is any clear efficiency gain?

Comment: @A Haworth, it's more of a general question and as I mentioned in my case it's just moving an image back and forth under a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the current approach is better because:

- There's significantly less data downloaded by the browser.
- The browser doesn't need to decompress and store all frames of the GIF.
- This effect can probably be done exclusively in the [compositor](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/inside-browser-part4/).

Also, GIF is a rather bad format for today's standards. It only supports 256 different colors for each frame and there are much better image compression schemes than the one used by GIF. An animated WebP/AVIF or an H.264/VP9/AV1 video would be a much better alternative, but in this simple case CSS animations are the most efficient method.

Answer (score -1):

Using a WebP image for your moving button would generally be a better choice. It provides smaller file sizes and better animation capabilities compared to GIF.

---

### Here are some references and resources related to using WebP and GIF images for web development:

---

**WebP References:**

Google Developers - WebP: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp

Official documentation from Google about the WebP image format, including details about compression, supported features, and usage.
Can I Use - WebP: https://caniuse.com/webp

---

**GIF References:**

MDN Web Docs - GIF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types#gif

Detailed information about the GIF image format, its features, limitations, and usage considerations.
GIPHY - GIF Guide: https://giphy.com/gifguide

---

**Performance Optimization:**

Smashing Magazine - "Image Optimization": https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/05/image-optimization-webp-avif/#using-the-webp-format

Google Developers - "Optimize images": https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization